# A newly opened tab in Chrome will sometimes close at random

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I've got a very curious problem in Google Chrome that's been giving me trouble for the past month or so, and I don't seem to be able to find a solution anywhere. Upon opening a new tab, there's a small chance that it will randomly close itself, and not after any set amount of time; it's pretty much random, and only happens a few times a day, so it's no more than a nuisance. Once I've switched to the new tab and begin typing, it will close itself without any warning or reason. My first thought was that my Chrome installation was messed up, but I also re installed Windows 7 yesterday, and it still happens on a fresh installation. The only other thing I can think of is an extension might be doing it, Awesome New Tab Page, but I'd like to consult SU before contacting others, I tend to see much quicker results and the community is very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Try disabling the extension first and see if it still happens. Also if your Ctrl key is faulting or u keep pressing it you might be using Ctrl+W to close the tab.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it was the extension, as I thought

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the extension

You may also want to [report the issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315)